# Custom MKAnnotation Image goes back to default when I attempt to drag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkannotation

I've got a bunch of MKAnnotations that don't need dragging.  I set this by `[pin setDraggable:NO]`.  I'm having an issue when I touch the annotation and (accidentally) drag off an annotation, it instantly looses it's custom image and changes back to the default red pin.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the viewForAnnotation delegate method, ***make sure the view is created as an MKAnnotationView*** and not an MKPinAnnotationView (which is a subclass of MKAnnotationView that automatically provides a pin image).

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I totally thought you had it - maybe I'm still overlooking something?  I've now got my MKAnnotationView AND my custom MKAnnotation objects as setDraggable:NO (set in the viewForAnnotation delegate) and still same issue...

Comment: Ah - got it - I see where you were going with that.  Changed how the view was created (using MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView) and it works.  Brilliant!  Thanks a million!

Comment: Thanks for this. Saved me a lot of time ripping my hair out for such a simple thing. :)