# Custom MKPinAnnotationView image

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm having a strange issue with the initial set of pins not showing the custom image.

In my

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

Method I set the image as follows:

```
pushPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shopping_map_pin"];
```

However, for the first set of pins, this image is not being set. If I set the pin color in the same method, that is applied but not the image.

What is causing this?

Comment: Are u able to post your full code in viewForAnnotation?

Comment: Sounds like you're creating MKPinAnnotationViews instead of MKAnnotationViews.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9814988/467105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that yes, I was using MKPinAnnotationView instead of MKAnnotationView. MKAnnotationView is more generic and allows for custom images to be loaded. That being said, it seems that when a view is recycled, an MKPinAnnotationView will use the image it was initially assigned.