# Pins with dynamic text in MapKit?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview

Is it possible to display dynamic text instead of a standard pin drop in MapKit?

For instance, the Trulia app shows house prices instead of a drop pin on their app, I'm wondering if they just have 10,000 pin images and are calling them like 4000.png or 5000.png or if they are somehow using dynamic pins and setting the text when the annotation is called.

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is totally possible. In `viewForAnnotation` just make your image, or use a cached one, according to the data you are trying to display at that point. Then set that as the annotation's `image` property.

Comment: here's a more complete answer you'd have found with a little more searching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view

Comment: I know I can display an image, what I'm hoping to do is display dynamic text in place of the pin image.

Comment: My point is to make an image dynamically in `viewForAnnotation` that contains the text you want to display. An image of text. You can't just float a UILabel on the map if that's what you're expecting.

Comment: In my question I asked if it was possible to display 'dynamic' text instead of a standard pin drop in MapKit, I'm sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: So render your dynamic text into a dynamic image. e.g. calculate your text, turn it into a string. Draw that string into an image, use that image.

Comment: Oh! I can render a dynamic image on the fly?! I missunderstood what you were saying, thanks for the info.