# How to give a location coordinate to plot a point in a map in ios using storyboard?

Tags: ios, mapkit, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am creating a map view in a view controller, using storyboard.

When I use the following code.

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationDistance distance = 1000;   
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate,
                               distance, 
                               distance);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjusted_region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjusted_region animated:YES];
}
```

A point is plotted in San Francisco, CA, United States. The
 `userLocation` coordinates are the predefined value in `MapKit.h` framework.
Now I create a

```
-(void) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    CLLocationDistance distance = 1000;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate;
    myCoordinate.latitude = 13.04016;
    myCoordinate.longitude = 80.243044;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(myCoordinate, 
                                                                   distance, 
                                                                   distance);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjusted_region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjusted_region animated:YES];
}
```

Here, the region is displayed having the coordinate in the center. But, no point is plotted at the coordinate position.

How to plot a point or annotation in that coordinate location?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this code inside of didUpdateUserLocation method

```
    MKPointAnnotation*    annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D myCoordinate;
    myCoordinate.latitude=13.04016;
    myCoordinate.longitude=80.243044;
    annotation.coordinate = myCoordinate;
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: Ya,thank u, this works perfect, can we use any icons(own Pictures) other than annotation.

Comment: You can use -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {} this method to customize annotation.

Comment: You can get idea through this link http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in didUpdateUserLocation

```
MKAnnotation *annotation = [[MKAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)];
[myMap addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: Three errors are displayed, use of undeclared identifier "Annotation".

Comment: Its MKAnnotation not Annotation

Comment: No, it is not working, any way thank u, but the first answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..
    //MAP VIEW Point

```
MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

//Center
CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
center.latitude=latitude;
center.longitude=longitude;

//Span
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;
span.longitudeDelta=THE_SPAN;

myRegion.center=center;
myRegion.span=span;

//Set our mapView
[MapViewC setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];

//Annotation

//1.create coordinate for use with the annotation
CLLocationCoordinate2D wimbLocation;
wimbLocation.latitude=latitude;
wimbLocation.longitude=longitude;

Annotation * myAnnotation= [Annotation alloc];

myAnnotation.coordinate=wimbLocation;
```

Comment: THE_SPAN 0.01f                                                                               In the place of latitude and longitude give your value...

Comment: Wat is that above comment

Comment: In the above coding in the place of  
THE_SPAN give value 0.01f,and in the place of latitude and longitude give your latitude and longitude values..

Comment: k, wat is that MapViewC

Comment: you would have declared the map view in .h file. Use the same name here and try.

Comment: Ya, thank u, can we plot our own pictures instead of annotation

Comment: check it here      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view