# How to add custom title view to mapview annotation in storyboard ios

Tags: ios, ios7, annotations, mkmapview

How to add custom title view to `mapview` `annotation` in ios

```
annotationPoint.title = @"title";            
annotationPoint.subtitle = @"sub title";    
[iMapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];                
[iMapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
```

I struggled a lot if any idea would be appreciable , Thanks in advance.

Simply i just wanna add view to annotation's title in storyboard.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449716/custom-annotation-apple-mapkit

Comment: heck this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24426521/how-to-add-image-in-annotation-in-mkmap/24426700#24426700