# Pin Annotation as Subview on map

Tags: swift, mapkit

Here's what i'm expect : 
[image]

as I know, annotationView cannot contain view. Anyone help me. thanks alot.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/jpsim/JPSThumbnailAnnotation). Is pretty old and in ObjC but you can reuse the logic and adapt it for your use-case