# MKPinAnnotationView custom Image is replaced by pin with animating drop

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I'm displaying user avatar images on a MapView. The avatars appear to be working if they are rendered without animation, however I'd like to animate their drop. If I set pinView.animatesDrop to true, then I lose the avatar and it is replaced by the pin. How can I animate the drop of my avatar without using the pin?

Here is my viewForAnnotation method I'm using:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyAnnotation"];

    if (!pinView) {
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotation"];
    }
    else
        pinView.annotation = annotation;

    //If I set this to true, my image is replaced by the pin
    //pinView.animatesDrop = true;

    //I'm using SDWebImage
    [pinView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/pathtosomeavatar.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    //Adding a nice drop shadow here
    pinView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    pinView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    pinView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    pinView.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;

    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view

Comment: Anna's link answers my question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view

Comment: Anna, please make your comment an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you want to use your own image for an annotation view, it's best to create a regular `MKAnnotationView` instead of an `MKPinAnnotationView`.

Since `MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, it has an `image` property but it generally (usually when you don't expect it) ignores it and displays its built-in pin image instead.

So rather than fighting with it, it's best to just use a plain `MKAnnotationView`.

The big thing you lose by not using `MKPinAnnotationView` is the built-in drop animation which you'll have to implement manually.

See this previous answer for more details:
[MKMapView: Instead of Annotation Pin, a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view)

Answer (score 3):

If you're stumbling on to this issue and you're sure that you're `MKAnnotationView` instead of an `MKPinAnnotationView`, ensure your `MKMapView`'s delegate property hasn't been nilled.