# MKAnnotationView custom image is not shown

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am trying to add a custom image instead of the regular pin on the map. But it remains a red pin... What am I missing?

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{  
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomPin.png"];
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501341/mkpinannotationview-custom-image-is-replaced-by-pin-with-animating-drop

Comment: Your code worked, but the animatesDrop is missing. I added pinView.animatesDrop = YES; but there is an error - property animatesDrop not found on MKAnnotationView. So that fixed it : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2087253/1341180

Comment: If you would put this link as an answer, I will check it as correct

Comment: Yes, as the linked answer says, need to use MKAnnotationView but it doesn't have animatesDrop property.  There's another answer linked in that answer that explains a workaround.  Feel free to answer this question yourself with the corrections you made.

Comment: I have updated the comment- the solution for missing drop functionality found above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MKMapView: Instead of Annotation Pin, a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view)

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 
    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) 
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                         initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        //pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; 
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinks.jpg"];    //as suggested by Squatch
    } 
    else {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi just remove one line from your code... `annView.animatesDrop = TRUE;`

Remain Code-

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{  
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomPin.png"];
    return annView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it helpful to look at Apples Documentation and download the sample code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746

They are implementing a custom annotation for their map.