# Creating a custom map annotation callout with an image, accessing data from an array

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I have a parsed a set of data from a JSON file (see example below):

```
{
    "locations": [

        {
            "id": "0001",
            "name": "Helensburgh Tunnels",
            "type": "Tunnels, Beach, Views",
            "location": "Helensburgh, South Coast",
            "image": "Helensburgh-Tunnels.jpg",
            "activity": "Walking, photography, tunnelling",
            "isVisited": false,
            "latitude": -34.178985,
            "longitude": 150.992867
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to correctly read all of this data into a TableView (everything works correctly), however, I would also like to display all of the locations within the JSON file as annotations on a MapView. So far, everything appears correctly except for a preview image on the left side of the callout box (all the annotation pins appear, when clicked they show a callout with a title and subtitle, but no image).

What do I need to resolve so that I can show this image? I am able to achieve it in other sections of my app, where only one location is shown, however, I cannot seem to figure out how to add images to all the annotation callouts within this view.

[image]

This is the code I am using to populate the annotations in my NearMeMapViewController:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class NearMeMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var nearMeMap: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var locations = [Location]()
    var location:Location!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // parse json
        if let locationJson = readLocation(){
            if let locationArray = locationJson["locations"] as? [[String:Any]]{
                for location in locationArray{
                    locations.append(Location.init(locationInfo: location))
                }
                print(locations.count)
            }
        }
        // end parse json

        nearMeMap.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.nearMeMap.showsUserLocation = true

        // Show annotation
        for location in locations {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = location.name
            annotation.subtitle = location.type
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
            nearMeMap.addAnnotation(annotation)

        }

    }


    // Start test - Custom annotation callout with image
    func nearMeMap (_ nearMeMap: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        let identifier = "MyPin"

        if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {
        return nil
        }

        // Reuse the annotation if possible
        var annotationView:MKPinAnnotationView? = nearMeMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        }

        let leftIconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 53))
        leftIconView.image = UIImage(named: location.image)
        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView

        return annotationView
    }
    // End test
```

I would really appreciate any help! I'm a student and I'm just learning, so sorry if I've used any incorrect terminology or there are noob mistakes.

Comment: Have you set the map view delegate, and is your view controller inheriting `MKMapViewDelegate`?

Comment: Is this what you mean? // Start code //

class NearMeMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

Comment: Yes, for the second part of my question. But have you set the mapView's delegate either using storyboards or by using code like this: `mapView.delegate = self`

Comment: should it not be 
    nearMeMap.delegate = self

Comment: Probably. Not all your code is there so I was just assuming. It is whatever you called your Map View variable.

Comment: Please see the updated code in my question (includes everything in that ViewController). Still no luck with the images.

Comment: hide your basic `Callout` to show your custom image  annotationView?.canShowCallout = false.   check my ans..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Swift 3.0**

On above code the `MKMapViewDelegate` should be

```
func mapView (_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{...}
```

and not

```
func nearMeMap (_ nearMeMap: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {...}
```

Add `var currentIndex = 0` as global declaration to identify the current image index. else, you aware to use `id` from `JSON` response.

i.e., Global Scope becomes like below code,

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var locations = [Location]()
//test variable? implemented to resolve issue with images in custom callout
var location:Location!

var currentIndex = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {...}
```

Then, the `leftIconView` will becomes,

```
let leftIconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 53))

var images = [String]()
for location in locations{
    images.append(location.image)
}
leftIconView.image = UIImage(named: images[currentIndex])
self.currentIndex = self.currentIndex+1 //0,1,2,3...N.
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: I've already set the delegate - please check my updated code in the question. This still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @joshlorschy , I was typed this first answer before you update the question .  Try optional solution. It will be work

Comment: I've tried that too with no luck :/ Would you be happy to zip and send me your test project?

Comment: @joshlorschy , see my updated answer. It'll help you to find a exact solution.

Comment: up voted for the effort, and pictures shows it works

Comment: @joshlorschy , see the exact answer :)

Comment: Nearly there! The images now appear, but all of the images are assigned to the wrong location (the wrong images appear in the callout boxes).

Comment: And the app crashes if i try to move the map while the callout is active

Answer (score 0):

when you want to set custom image for annotation view, prefer `MKAnnotationView` instead of an `MKPinAnnotationView`. You can set your custom image as annotation by setting it as `Image` attribute of `MKAnnotationView` . Check [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview) for more info on MKAnnotationView .

As `MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, it has an image property but it generally (usually when you don't expect it) ignores it and displays its built-in pin image instead.

So it's best to just use a plain `MKAnnotationView`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501341/mkpinannotationview-custom-image-is-replaced-by-pin-with-animating-drop) answer for more details.You can use `MKAnnotationView` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829962/mkannotationview-custom-image-is-not-shown).

----- EDIT -----

hide your basic `Callout` to show your custom image.

```
 annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
```

Refer this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793315/customize-mkannotation-callout-view) to customize `CallOut` images.  Check [this](http://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/) link for the detailed tutorial.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: If you read the question, he isn't trying to change the pin image, but rather have an image on the callout view.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I got your point @TristanBeaton. I will leave the ans in case any one needs in future. Thanks.

Comment: in your nearMeMap comment out annotationView?.canShowCallout = true. Can't try the same as I am away from my system. Btw I have also added a link for your reference. Hope it helps.

Comment: Check this link for well explained tutorial. http://sweettutos.com/2016/03/16/how-to-completely-customise-your-map-annotations-callout-views/

Comment: You can also have a look at Rob's ans [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772108/custom-mkannotation-callout-bubble-with-button/17772487#17772487). He has explained 3 diffrerent ways to create custom callout view.