# Swift - MKPinAnnotation image issue

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I'm trying to change my pin annotation image to something other than the pin.

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "pin"

        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
            pinView!.pinColor = .Green
            pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "icon1.png")

            // Add image to left callout
            var mugIconView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.png"))
            pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = mugIconView

            // Add detail button to right callout
            var calloutButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView
```

Everything works except changing the pin image. I have a custom point annotation subclass which is this

I've been searching for hours but every other SO question I've found hasn't helped. I'd appreciate any help... thanks.

**UPDATED WITH ANSWER**

```
   func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("pin")

    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")

        // Add image to left callout
        var mugIconView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.png"))
        pinView!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = mugIconView

        // Add detail button to right callout
        var calloutButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `MKAnnotationView`, not `MKPinAnnotationView`. Pin annotations can't customize their image.

See [this SO answer for additional details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640785/157142)