# MKPinAnnotationView doesn't set custom image

Tags: ios, xcode, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I have to set custom image for different pins. With my code I'm able to set custom color for each of them but when I try to set custom image instead of colors, it doesn't work.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(MyAnnotation *)annotation {

static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil) {

        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    } else {

        annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    }

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;

    NSString *stringType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [(MyAnnotation *)annotationView.annotation stringType]];

    if ([stringType isEqualToString:@"0"]) {

        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconUserCerco.png"];
        //annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    } else if ([stringType isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IconUserDefault.png"];
        //annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    } else if ([stringType isEqualToString:@"2"]) {

        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PinUniversity.png"];
        //annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    }

    return annotationView;

}

return nil;
```

}

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MKPinAnnotationView custom Image is replaced by pin with animating drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501341/mkpinannotationview-custom-image-is-replaced-by-pin-with-animating-drop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `MKPinAnnotationView` can you use `MKAnnotationView`? You'll have to use following instead of `MKPinAnnotationView`

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [self.myMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
```

iOS 9.0 onwards its recommended to use `MKAnnotationView`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like in iOS 11.x Swift 4, note this won't work if you make the same mistake as me using **MKPinAnnotationView**. This will make a pin and you won't be able to change the image behind it.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation  {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pav:MKAnnotationView?
    if (pav == nil)
    {
        pav = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pav?.isDraggable = true
        pav?.canShowCallout = true
        pav?.image = UIImage(named: "WIP.png")
        pav?.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -8, y: 0)
        pav?.autoresizesSubviews = true
//      pav?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        pav?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .contactAdd)
    }
    else
    {
        pav?.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return pav;
}
```